# Need to bifurcate pom.xml based on the requirement

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, maven-2

I have one project in GIT, which I am cloning and running my tests through Maven and selenium.

Now I want to run those test-cases against Jenkins CI.

Since I have multiple projects in GIT, I have multiple pom.xml in my repository..

My question is - How can I run specific project on specific run.. If I want to run project1 first and then I want to run project2 by just changing the pom.xml through command line. How can I do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running mvn command with "-f" option ? You can specify which file you want to run with  "mvn -f filename.xml". I'm not sure to understand what your specific need is ...

Comment: Or you can execute your "mvn" job in the project directory you want to build. For example, if you have /project1/pom.xml and /project2/pom.xml, you can choose which project run first by setting your working directory in /project1 or in /project2 then running your mvn command.

Comment: Thanks @Morgan, I applied second solution and it worked. I am using jenkins where I just found one option for specifying the POM file path.. Made my day. :)

Comment: Glad to know it. I added the answer. Can you validate the answer ? In order to tag the question as resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute your "mvn" job in the project directory you want to build. For example, if you have /project1/pom.xml and /project2/pom.xml, you can choose which project run first by setting your working directory in /project1 or in /project2 then running your mvn command.